# Why does Ctrl-C terminates screen when ran in detached mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, gnu-screen

If I use `Ctrl-C` in a screen I ran the "normal way" using `screen -S screen_name`, it behaves as expected meaning it will interrupt whatever command the screen is running **but won't terminate the screen itself**.

However, when I run screen in **detached** mode using `screen -dmS screen_name command`, it works fine but when I reattach the screen, `Ctrl-C` will **terminates the screen itself**.

How can I prevent `Ctrl-C` from terminating the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen exits when the command it is running finishes.

In your first example you don't specify a command, so your default shell will be started.

In your second example, you don't specify a shell so your command is run directly. When that command receives the `Ctrl-C`, it will quit and so the screen will close.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can use the `zombie`, `defzombie` or `onerror` options to screen to make the window stick around after the command has quit.

Alternatively, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/362756/keep-gnu-screen-window-open-after-program-terminates) answer contains a suggestion for keeping a bash shell open after an initial script terminates.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. I basically wanted bash to run after my command is terminated so I ended up doing: `screen -dmS screen_name bash -c 'command;exec bash'`